# Multiple requirements while sorting a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, namely `[(7, 14), (3, 12), (20, 22), (6, 14), (2, 12)]`.
I want to sort it by the second value in the tuple, but if the second values are the same, I want the earlier element in a sorted list to be with the lower first value. For more clarity `(6,14)` should be earlier in the sorted list, then `(7, 14)`.

Right now I have the following code:

```
result = [(7, 14), (3, 12), (20, 22), (6, 14), (2, 12)]
result.sort(key = lambda a: a[1])
Output[]: [(3, 12), (2, 12), (7, 14), (6, 14), (20, 22)]
```

What I want is:

```
Output[]: [(2, 12), (3, 12), (6, 14), (7, 14), (20, 22)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort as if the elements of the tuples were reversed.

```
>>> ts = [(7, 14), (3, 12), (20, 22), (6, 14), (2, 12)]
>>> ts.sort(key=lambda t: t[::-1])
>>> ts
[(2, 12), (3, 12), (6, 14), (7, 14), (20, 22)]
```

`sort` and `sorted` sort lexicographically by default, which means that if the first element of whatever is sorted matches, then it looks at the second element, and so on.

`lambda t: (t[1], t[0])` would also have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `itemgetter` in place of a `lambda`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
result = [(7, 14), (3, 12), (20, 22), (6, 14), (2, 12)]

print(sorted(result, key=itemgetter(1, 0)))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 12), (3, 12), (6, 14), (7, 14), (20, 22)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
result = sorted(result, key=lambda k :(k[1], k[0]))
print(result)
```

Output:-

```
[(2, 12), (3, 12), (6, 14), (7, 14), (20, 22)]
```